# Как использовать кеширование в Котлин

Tags: javascript, kotlin, кэширование

Здесь у меня есть простой пример Фибоначчи, как я использую идею кеширования в JS. Есть ли такая же идея кэширования в `Kotlin`?

Вот краткий пример того, как поменять местами в `JS`
[а, б] = [б, а]; А есть ли пример на `Kotlin`?

```
function fib(n) {
    if (n < 2){
      return n
    }
    return fib(n - 1) + fib (n - 2)
  }
  function cachingDecorator(func) {
    let cache = new Map();
    return function(x) {
      if (cache.has(x)) {    // если кеш содержит такой x,
        return cache.get(x); // читаем из него результат
      }
      let result = func(x); // иначе, вызываем функцию
      cache.set(x, result); // и кешируем (запоминаем) результат
      return result;
    };
  }
  
  fib = cachingDecorator(fib);
  
  console.log(fib(6))
```

`Kotlin` пример:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val n = 10
    var t1 = 0
    var t2 = 1
    
    print("First $n terms: ")

    for (i in 1..n) {
        print("$t1 + ")

        val sum = t1 + t2
        t1 = t2
        t2 = sum
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К примеру есть [HashMap](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-hash-map/)

Использование:

```kotlin
var map: HashMap<Int, Int> = HashMap<Int, Int>()
map.put(10, 9999)
if (map.containsKey(10)) {
    println("Result: " + map.get(10))
}
```

Comment: А можно ли передать аргумент как функция для мап?
Я насщет моего кода @BigTows ?

Comment: @ԽաչատուրՄելքոնյան здесь аналог `cache.set(x, result);` выступает `map.put(10, 9999)`

Comment: Ок спасибо!!!!!